# pass a hash as an argument in assigning attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
     def menu_params
          params.permit(menu: [:name]).require(:menu)                   
          end    

        def update
        if @menu.update(menu_params)              ------->line 29
          render json: @menu
        else
          render json: @menu.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end

       def set_menu
         @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
        end
```

http request (postman rest client). This is a PUT(update) request to edit both records in menu table. with id's attached in the url.
http://localhost:3000/menus/1,3

```
{
"menu": [
     {
       "name":"breakfast12"
     },

     {
       "name":"lunch 12"
     }

  ] 
}
```

This is part of the code I have. I am trying to update multiple rows in a single request.

I have also configured collections in `routes.rb`

But I am facing this error.

> # PATCH/PUT /menus/1    ArgumentError in MenusController#update
>   When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

Pointing at line 29.

Is there a way to traverse through the specified ids in the url? As seen here it shows only `/menus/1`.

And is there a way to specify the id's in the json request stub?

Comment: please post your parameters

Comment: Try `params.require(:menu).permit(name: [])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def menu_params
  params.require(:menu).permit(:name)                
end
```

Comment: That wont work. Tried it initially. It throws this error.

 undefined method `permit' for [{"name"=>"breakfast12"}, {"name"=>"lunch 12"}]:Array

Its cause of strong parameters.

Comment: What version of rails are you on?